# PHP - Send email from users address

Tags: php, html, email, gmail

I have a form on my website where users can type a message and their email, and it will be sent to my address. I have installed PHPMailer for another task, but I am using PHP's built in `mail()` function because I thought it would work better as it's only a simple task.

However, it does not seem to be working - emails are not sent. Here is my code:

```
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Email from " . $_POST["name"];
$txt = $_POST["message"];
$headers = "From: " . $_POST["email"];

if (mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers)) {
    // Success
} else {
    // Failed
}
```

Everything is posted correctly, it's just the `mail()` function that returns false. Why is this happening? Should I use PHPMailer instead?

Comment: Did you check your SMTP Authentication ?

Comment: hard to say if the form's ok. if it returned false then something failed. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php yet, using error reporting will be useless if your form's method doesn't use "post" and with POST arrays, strangely enough.

Comment: GMail is going to reject mails with fake From: addresses anyway.

Comment: Alex, what do you mean?